# Conditional Formatting: Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

This is what I am trying to accomplish: in each row, IF column A has a duplicate value, AND the corresponding color value from column B are not the same, highlight cell.

```
       A     B
   1   X     Blue  
   2   X     Red  
   3   Y     Blue  
   4   Y     Blue
```

`A1:B1` and `A2:B2` would be highlighted because `X` is a duplicate value but the corresponding colors in the same rows do not match.

While  `A3:B3` and `A4:B4` should pass (not receive highlight) because even though `Y` is a duplicate, the corresponding colors do match.

*Is this possible and how?*

Comment: I'm not very experienced in excel formulas so I haven't really gotten too far. I start by highlighting both columns and selecting new rule under conditional formatting. I start to write it out with IF(And(Count(...)>2 ???) the question marks are where I get lost.

Comment: Normally I just used the "canned" conditional formatting but this time I couldn't change them to work as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a CF rule using a formula.  For your example data:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$4,A1)<>COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$4,A1,$B$1:$B$4,B1)
```

Update if applying to both ColA and B:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$4,$A1)<>COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$4,$A1,$B$1:$B$4,$B1)
```

Comment: My version of the same formula `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$4,$A1,$B$1:$B$4,"<>" & $B1)>0`.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you for your answer! Paritally worked. I want to highlight all four cells A1 and B1 AND A2 and B2. With that calculation with my cells/cell ranges dropped in only works for the first row of the range. It didnt work down the column further, and it only highlighted A1 even if the mismatch color was in A2.

Comment: Okay, both cells highlight but only in the first row. For example If I change cell B4 to say purple, it does not highlight. This is my current calculation "=COUNTIF($B$3:$B$700,$B3)<>COUNTIFS($B$3:$B700, $B3,$C$3:$C$700,$C3)"               Again Thank you for your help, Im sure your answer is correct, I probably wasnt specific enough in my original question.

Comment: Ok, so in the count if statement "$A1" is the criteria, so further down the column I have duplicates in say A26, its not recognizing or highlighting. Also, The only cell that is receiving the highlight is the A1:B1 range even though A2:B2 technically should be highlighted as well. @TimWilliams

Comment: Works for me - if you can share your workbook I can take a look.